# Display Images in an Array

Tags: javascript

I have an array likes this

```
<script>

var myFruit = new Array("Apple", "orange", "banana", "plum", "pear");

var myindex = prompt("enter 0 to 4","");

document.write(myFruit[myindex]);

</script>
```

It will prompt a window and user enter a number then get result.

Now I don't want a prompt, I want to display the fruit in order like: My 1 fruit is an Aplle.

How can I write a code so that when I enter 1, then it will show: My 1 fruit is an (image) Apple.  When I enter 2, it will show: My 2 fruit is an (image) orange....

I don't know how to get the index changed, then it will show both index and value simultaneously.

Please give me a hand .  Thanks

```
------------------------------------------------------
```

From the help of user2782160, I have another concern below

I have 5 images put in an array likes this

```
<script>

var myDegree = new Array("30.gif", "60.gif", "90.gif", "120.gif", "150.gif");

.........

</script>
```

I need to write code somehow to have

```
<div id="degreeCount"> 30</div><div>//image 30.gif has to show inside this div</div>
```

I mean 30.gif will show next to the number 30.

Please give me a hand.  Thank you!

Comment: If you don't want to use promt, how do you plan to receive user's input then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concatenate the strings:

```
var myindex = parseInt(prompt("enter 0 to 4", ""), 10);
document.write ('My ' + myindex + ' fruit is an ' + myFruit[myindex]);
```

Comment: From the help of user2782160, I have another concern. Please take a look at the second part of my question.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

something like this i guess?

```
for(i = 0; i<myFruit.length; i++){
    document.write("My "+i+" fruit is an <img src='URL HERE MINUS FRUIT NAME'"+myFruit[i]+".jpg>");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  Please take a look at the second part of my question.  Thank you